# python use function without waiting for it's return (fire and forget)?

Tags: python-3.x, process, python-asyncio, fire-and-forget

I want to download file and save it inside `files` folder with `dwd` function but i don't want to wait till the file is downloaded i want to run download function in the background and make response to view with files function i tried to use `multiprocessing.Process` not working as expected.

```
 def files(request):
     # Get papram needed
     g_id = request.GET.get('g_id')
     d_id = request.GET.get('d_id')
     o_id = request.GET.get('o_id')
     m_id  = request.GET.get('m_id')


    download_url = (f"http://example.com/embed?video={m_id}&d=1")
    r = requests.head(download_url)
    content_length = r.headers['Content-length']
    video_path_name = (f'streamapp/static/files/{did}_{m_id}.mp4')

    if os.path.exists(video_path_name):
        currnt_lenght = os.path.getsize(video_path_name)
        progress = (int(currnt_lenght) *100)/ int(content_length)
        progress = round(progress, 2)
    else:
        run_download = Process(target=dwd_file(filepath=video_path_name, download_url=download_url))
        run_download.daemon = True
        run_download.start()
        progress = '0'

    context = {'g_id': g_id, 'd_id': d_id,
               'o_id': o_id, 'm_id': m_id,
               'video_path_name': video_path_name,
               'download_url': download_url,
               'progress': progress}
    return render(request, 'pages/upload.html', context)


def dwd_file(filepath, download_url):
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        r = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content():
                f.write(chunk)
```